# SQL to update the salary of employees with their department's average salary

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

Consider the table `employee`:

```
desc employee;

Name                       Null?    Type
-------------------------- -------- ------------
EMPLOYEENO                 NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
ENAME                               VARCHAR2(15)
JOB                                 VARCHAR2(15)
MGR                                 NUMBER(4)
HIREDATE                            DATE
SAL                                 NUMBER
COMM                                NUMBER
DEPTNO                              NUMBER(2)
```

Contains with values of `deptno`,`sal` as:

```
    DEPTNO      SAL
---------- ----------
        10     2450
        10     5000
        10     1300
        20     2975
        20     3000
        20     1100
        20      800
        20     3000
        30     1250
        30     1500
        30     1600
        30      950
        30     2850
        30     1250
```

Need to update the salary of employees with **their** department's average salary.
i.e set every employee's salary to the departmental average.Is there any solution possible with the group by clause something like

```
update employee set sal =(select avg(sal) from employee group by deptno) where deptno in(select deptno from employee group by deptno)
```

So how to query the same.

Comment: I swear I've seen a very similar question around these parts before...

Comment: Do you mean you want to update the salary of every employee who has an average salary?  Or set every employee's salary to the departmental average?

Comment: Possible related questions from your class: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=employee+%22sal%22+%22deptno%22

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE A
SET SAL = (SELECT AVG(SAL) FROM EMPLOYEE B WHERE B.DEPTNO = A.DEPTNO);
```

Comment: Thanks..The query gives the correct output.
But is there any way to obtain the same with group by clause.i jst tried one it didn't work though.

update employee set sal =(select avg(sal) from employee group by deptno) where deptno in(select deptno from employee group by deptno)

Comment: @rijinrv, my query is doing exactly what you mentioned in your comment, you don't need `GROUP BY` and `IN` here

Answer (score 0):

```
update employee a
set sal =  (select avg(sal) as avgsal
          from employee b
          where A.DEPTNO = b.deptno
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be much more efficiently implemented as a MERGE, in which the USING clause aggregates salaries for all departments to the department level and joins to the employee table on department_id.