# Groub by clause in sql

Tags: sql, select

To find the names of the employee who receive salary less than every average salary for each type of job
The given solution is:

```
SELECT ENAME,JOB,SAL
FROM EMP
   WHERE SAL<ALL
    (SELECT AVG(SAL) FROM EMP
      GROUP BY JOB);
```

All the columns specified in the `SELECT` clause MUST be present in the `GROUP BY` clause,but here it is not.The inner query’s `SELECT` clause does not contain job although it is specified in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544971/sql-to-update-the-salary-of-employees-with-their-departments-average-salary#comment20288302_14544971 your classmate?

Comment: And what, exactly, is your *question*?

Comment: Possible other questions from your class: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=employee+%22sal%22+%22deptno%22

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need to list all employees whose `SAL`ary is less than the average of all salary on each `JOB`.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    EMP a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  JOB, AVG(SAL) avg_sal
            FROM    EMP
            GROUP   BY JOB
        ) b ON a.JOB = b.JOB
WHERE   a.SAL < b.avg_sal
```